# Как сравнить два типа данных в golang?

Tags: golang

Застопорилась на простенькой задаче при изучении Go. Суть в чем. Пользователь вводит произвольную строку в консоль. Делаем это через fmt.Scanln(), тут все понятно. Далее же необходимо вывести "True" если строка состоит из цифр и "False" во всех остальных случаях. И я не совсем понимаю, как это сделать. В пайтоне есть встроенная функция bool(), а вот как это реализовано в Go это не совсем понятно. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, вот решение этой простой, но очень интересной для новичка задачи. Суть решения состоит в том, что бы при конвертации inputa в int проверять, сконвертировался ли он, если же нет, то выдавать False.

```js
package main

import (
 "bufio"
 "log"
 "os"
 "strconv"
)

func main() {
 trues()
}

func trues() {
 if err := one(); err != nil {
  log.Println("False")
  return
 }
 // success
 log.Println("True")
}

func one() error {
 input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
 if input.Scan() {
  _, err := strconv.Atoi(input.Text())
  if err != nil {
   return err
  }
 }
 return input.Err()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из вопроса, СТРОКА ПРОИЗВОЛЬНАЯ! А значит strconv.Atoi вернёт error "value out of range" если значение не поместится в памяти для типа int!

Как вариант проверить строку регуляркой: `^\d*$` или, что аналогично:
`^[0-9]*$`.

```
test:="1233455677789900066554436433"
pattern:=`^\d*$`

matched,err:= regexp.Match(pattern, 
                      []byte(test))

// ...Обработка ошибки на усмотрение, но если шаблон написан синтаксически верно, err будет nil

//true
```

Answer (score -3):

Попробуйте примерно так

```
fmt.Printf("%v", strings.ContainsAny(s, "0123456789")
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YYEg0zz3tKX)
Сейчас проверка не верная, посмотрите на другие функции в пакете [strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ContainsAny)

Comment: Да, действительно помогло. Спасибо, что помогли разобраться.

Comment: Выведет true, если в строке есть хоть одна цифра. А это не то, что требуется. Для "nbh123" будет true, а должно быть false.

Comment: Да я знаю, но может это подтолкнёт на верный ответ.

Comment: Может быть проще всего пробежать по всем символам строки и сравнить каждый с '0' и '9'?

Comment: Не, я нашла более элегантное решение. Я конвертирую input в int, если он сконвертировался, то идет True, если нет то False.

Comment: Вы уверены? А если введут строку 11111111111111111111111